# Spring How to insert a raw JSON directly into mongo db without Parsing

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb

I want to insert the JSON string directly into mongo db, without parsing

```
String json = "{ 'name' : 'Vince' , " +
                "'website' : 'howtodoinjava.com' , " +
                "'address' : { 'addressLine1' : 'Some address' , " +
                              "'addressLine2' : 'Cardiff CF116LW' , " 
                              "'addressLine3' : 'Cardiff, UK'} }"

DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);

collection.insert(dbObject);
```

In the above example i don't want to use this line

```
DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(json);
```

Is there any out of the box solution for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

The [insert](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#insert-com.mongodb.DBObject...-) method takes one or more `DBObject` as parameters, so no you cannot pass a `String` instead.

There are [a few ways](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-insert-a-document/) to obtain a `DBObject`;

- Provide a string and parse it (as you did)
- Instantiate a [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#BasicDBObject()) with empy construtctor and use the [put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)) method for each field (`BasicDBObject` inherits from `HashMap`)
- Use the [BasicDBObjectBuilder](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObjectBuilder.html) utility
- Provide a `Map` and use the [BasicDBObject constructor that takes a Map](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html#BasicDBObject(java.util.Map))

Comment: thanks for the information, even I m using  BasicDBObject for one of the solution. Now just wanted to avoid in between parsing to java object.